# What privileges needed to deploy in Azure Pipelines

Tags: azure-devops

I'm trying to setup release pipeline.

When I add task Azure App Service Deploy and try to authorize, I get an error:

> Failed to create an app in Azure Active Directory. Error: Insufficient
>   privileges to complete the operation. Ensure that the user has
>   permissions to create an Azure Active Directory Application.

Question is: What privileges do I need to do this operation ?

[Screenshot of the error message](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DUUK0.png)

Answer (score 0):

[Application developer](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/users-groups-roles/directory-assign-admin-roles#application-developer-permissions) permissions should be adequate, because it grants `microsoft.directory/applications/createAsOwner`

```
Create applications in Azure Active Directory. Creator is added as the first owner, and the created object counts against the creator's 250 created objects quota.
```